# R - Returning the full joint probability distribution of a dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, probability, categorical-data

I have a data.frame with categorical variables as below:

```
bird.data <- data.frame( id =  rep(2,500),
                          colour = sample(c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"), 500, replace=T, c(0.15,0.45, 0.20, 0.20)),
                          size = sample(c("Large", "Medium","Small"), 500, replace = T, c(0.33,0.33, 0.33)),
                          texture = sample(c("Hard", "Soft"), 500, replace = T, prob = c(0.55,0.45))
)
```

Is there an easy way to return the full joint distribution, `P(colour,size,texture)` of the dataset using R? For the dataset above, this would be a cube with dimensions: `with(bird.data, levels(colour) * levels(size) * levels(texture))`.

For instance, for the dataset given above, I want to be able to store every information as below within the cube:

```
# P(colour="Red", size="Small", texture= "Hard")
p_Red_Small_Hard <- nrow(bird.data[ bird.data$colour== "Red" & bird.data$size == "Small" & bird.data$texture =="Hard", ]) / nrow(bird.data)
```

Comment: `with(bird,prop.table(table(colour,size,texture)))` ?

Comment: @Ben Bolker, thank you. I tried to make it more generic: `with(bird1.data,prop.table(table(colnames(bird1.data))))` so it applies to all columns without having to input the column names but R doesn't like it?

Comment: Try `table(bird.data[, -1]˙ to drop the id column?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, Thank you very much. Am I right in assuming I can apply the same code to however many categorical variables I wish? Also, how can I apply the normalising factor to translate the frequencies into probabilities?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and make sure? :)